What are the key differences in the directors cut of Dark City?
The 1998 movie Dark City is widely thought to be an under appreciated SciFi gem, overshadowed by blockbusters like The Matrix which shared some themes (and reused some sets!)
I only recently discovered that there was a Directors cut about 10-15min longer which is not easy to find on streaming. Some directors cuts seem to make the movie better (eg Blade Runner or Apocalypse Now) but others seem to undermine the experience by over-explaining, like Donny Darko).
Which type of director's cut is Dark City?
What are the key differences in the director's cut (not just in terms of extra or longer scenes, but in the way the theme and story play out and the resolution)?

https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0118929/alternateversions/

https://www.movie-censorship.com/report.php?ID=3551125
